# Run methods after all beans of the Spring's @Configuration class were loaded

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

Let's say there's a Spring class which looks like this.

```
@Configuration
public class Config {

    @Bean
    public BeanA beanA() {
        // ...
        return beanA;
    }
    
    @Bean
    public BeanB beanB() {
        // ...
        return beanB;
    }
    
    // ...
    
    @Bean
    public BeanN beanN() {
        // ...
        return beanN;
    }

    public void executeAfterAllBeans() {
        // some code
    }
}
```

My goal is to execute the `executeAfterAllBeans()` method right after, well, all the beans inside the `Config` class were loaded. How can I achieve that?

Comment: I think you could use `@EventListener(ContextStartedEvent.class)`

Comment: Events are definitely a good way for this. Unfortunately I couldn't find a complete list of Spring Boot's internal events, although there should be a list somewhere in the docs. Maby someone can give a link to it. However, here a maybe useful quick summary of what to do with which events: https://semotpan.com/spring-application-events-7ab5390db6dd

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use @PostConstruct annotation on this method and it will execute annotated method right after bean of class containing this method has been created with its properties e.g

```
@PostConstruct
public void executeAfterAllBeans() {
    // some code
}
```

If you just want to make sure it runs right after above beans have been created then you can pass those beans as method arguments but don't use if you don't need. This should force spring to wait until those beans are created before executing the method e.g

```
@PostConstruct
public void executeAfterAllBeans(BeanA beanA, BeanB beanB) {
// some code
}
```